# Finding Element with Constantly Changing Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

I am new to coding Selenium in Python and, I have been trying to find this button through name, id, xpath, and then click on it but nothing has worked.

The issue is, I cannot find the button because the xpath is constantly changing, and the ID name is just "button", which locating it that way would not work either because there are a lot of other buttons on the page. How can I located the element?

**Here is the sites HTML:**

```
<ul data-componentname="gender">

  <li id="b27296be-e8da-4d5a-acb6-d1674bf88568" class="">
    <input type="button">
    <span>Male</span>
  </li>

  <li id="32bf7074-6b69-41bb-9869-cf71ac42686f" class="">
    <input type="button">
    <span>Female</span>
  </li>
```

**Here is what I have tried:**

```
clickGender = browser.find_element_by_xpath("b27296be-e8da-4d5a-acb6-d1674bf88568")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: is `b27296be-e8da-4d5a-acb6-d1674bf88568` the constantly changing id? you want to click the male button?

Comment: Try this `find_element_by_xpath("//li[contains(.,'Male')]")`.

Answer (score 1):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to find the dynamic button corresponding to the text as **Male** or **Female** and then click on it you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- Male:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@data-componentname='gender']//li//span[contains(.,'Male')]//preceding::input[1]"))).click()
  ```
- Female:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@data-componentname='gender']//li//span[contains(.,'Female')]//preceding::input[1]"))).click()
  ```

**Note**: You need the following imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`find_element_by_id`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements):

```
clickGender = browser.find_element_by_id("b27296be-e8da-4d5a-acb6-d1674bf88568")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XPATH should be this (assuming you want to select the 'Male' button):

```
//li[span/text()='Male']
```

Answer (score 0):

> To find the button with text that contains "Male", use this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[contains(string(), 'Male')]/input[contains(@type,'button')]")
```

> To find the button with text that contains "Female", use this:

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[contains(string(), 'Female')]/input[contains(@type,'button')]")
```